# Check value of a variable while R session is running

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to check the value of a variable in the script while it is running? One way could be to setup print commands in the script to print the value of the variable periodically. But I forgot to do that and it is a long program. Is there any another way?

Comment: I've never seen that done. And I'd be very surprised if that was possible. It's a bit like telling a person to count to 1,000 after they jump into a swimming pool, wait at the bottom, and only come up when they have reached 1,000. Before they come up for air, you want to ask them what number they are up to. :P

Comment: Maybe a progress bar in your script could help you ? But it assume that you know the maximum value it will have during the script...

Comment: @Gowachin Is there a way to add a progress bar to an ongoing session? The thing is that my session has been running for a while. I don't want to stop it and start again

Comment: For the purpose of the image use before, it like asking the personn to count with a clock now, without him getting out the water. I don't think R work the way you want to do this...